# How does an addin retrieve and process data from the AddinRoot?

Tags: plugins, mono.addins

I'm planning to use Mono.Addins in my C#/.NET project.

For that, I've read the Programming Guide and Reference Manual presented in codeplex.com, downloaded the latest version of source code from github.com, and successfully built all the samples included in the source package. However, whether the online documents or sample projects, all try to demonstrate how to extend an AddinHost by creating new instances of an ExtensionNode. There seems to miss something about how to retrieve and process data from the AddinHost.

For example, say I have a text editor, which processes RTF document, and I want to provide the possibility for addins to find/replace the document with its own way (For example, Regex / Forward / Backward / Whole document / Current Line...), so the addin need to get the content from AddinHost first. This is the question I need an answer for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well you have to maintain a reference to the RTF document, I think that providing it inside an initialization code for your plugin could be a way to obtain it.

Or you can have a sort of "IFindReplaceAddin" with a method, say "FindReplace", that accepts the RTF document as argument and returns the elaborated document.